# How to configure honeywell barcode scanner to receive all QR-code bytes in keyboard mode

Tags: qr-code, barcode-scanner, honeywell

we use barcode scanner to develop software which uses qr-codes. Our QR-codes contain binary data which is easy to receive when scanner set to virtual com-port mode. But we need to receive this binary data when scanner is set to usb keyboard mode. So when reading qr-code it will have non-printable and extended ascii values. We managed to configure scanner to send binary data as keyboard symbols including non-printable values. But we are not able to receive extended ascii values.

**scanner**: 1950gsr-2-INT
**configuration** used:

- set default scanner settings,
- set USB keyborad (PC) mode (PAP124)
- set Control Character Output On (KBDNPE1) to receive non-printable ascii values
- tried to set ALT mode (KBDALT6 or KBDALT7) to receive extended ascii symbols, but this broke reading qr-code at all, so switched it off (KBDALT0)

example data:

- qr-code contains sequence of bytes (hex): { 5, 5, 1, 1, 0, B, 0, 0, 0, 17, 72, F0, AE, 1D, 9E, 99, D9, 78, 4C, 98, 40, }
- when scan this qr-code with barcode scanner then receive string: `[ENQ][ENQ][SOH][SOH][NUL][VT][NUL][NUL][NUL][ETB]r[GS]xL@[CR]`
  so this string does not contain symbols from extended ascii set (for example `F0` is not in the received string).

How to configure scanner to receive all bytes in keyboard mode? Maybe it is possible to receive not keyboard symbols but hex byte values?

Any help is apriciated, thank you.

Comment: There is such an article. [How to enable HEX dump mode on a hand held scanner?](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/How-to-enable-HEX-dump-mode-on-a-hand-held-scanner) The scanner you want to use doesn't seem to be on the list, but it may have been targeted as it's been a while since the article. Please ask the support desk.

Comment: @kunif It worked! Thank you so much for your help! You are the only to give the solution after the month of searching in documentation and asking official support and community

Comment: Please self-answer what you did and what the results were. It will help those who have similar problems later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set barcode scanner to hex dump mode as described in [Hex Dump Mode](https://honeywellsps.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#00000000SK3U/a/A00000000G8O/qPAq.3u_8tdLWbWTL5o9LvfMlQrsOz3ky0mqLUyFzxo). In this mode all bytes from qr-code are written to any text input field as string with hex values separated with space symbol.

[image]

Unfortunately this setting was not mentioned in official scanner documention and tutrials.

Thanks [@kunif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014308/kunif) who gave link with honeywell support answer for similar question
[How to enable HEX dump mode on a hand held scanner?](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/How-to-enable-HEX-dump-mode-on-a-hand-held-scanner)